# Why is Mr. Wayne collected by a man with a flashlight?

Tags: props, joker

During [the scene at the Charlie Chaplin show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDAXlpZfqdw) in *Joker*, right before the scene in the toilets, Mr. Wayne is collected by a man holding a flashlight.

[image]

Why is this? Why is he being summoned for what appears to be his own toilet break? And why does the man have a flashlight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a high end movie theatre, orchestra, opera, music, or concert hall, the ushers and security carry small flashlights. It is customary for the ushers to escort a patron to and from their seats if they have to enter or exit the darkened performance hall during the show. Although, the lights on stage or on the screen are significant. The aisles and stairs (normally concrete or carpeted concrete) are very dark. They are normally in the shadow of the seats. And, cellphone usage is usually prohibited.

I worked in venues like these through high school and university.  You kept alert for patrons trying to make their way through the dark. You remained ready at the moment so that you could prevent an accident which could, at best, interrupt the performance for other patrons, and at worst, cause an injury. Not only was this a hazard for the patrons, it was a hazard for the venue which could be held liable for injuries.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood this scene:

- Mr. Wayne is not collected or summoned by this man. Mr. Wayne stands up on his own for a toilet break, then this man (a body guard perhaps) shows a torch so that Mr Wayne can see better while on his way to a bathroom.

Comment: Why would you want or need a torch for that? Is that normal?

Comment: a theater is normally dark, no? When a person arrives late or leave early in a cinema, they would turn on their smartphone's torch.

Comment: The place is obviously well lit. You can even see two lights in the question's screenshot.

Comment: they are in a movie, a well-lit theater is expected. Otherwise, how do we as audience see? Besides, the corridor between Wayne's chamber and a toilet can be dark.

Comment: In a high end movie theatre, orchestra, opera, music, or concert hall, the ushers and security carry small flashlights. It is customary for the ushers to escort a patron to and from their seats if they have to enter or exit the darkened performance hall during the show. Although, the lights on stage or on the screen are significant. The stairs (normally concrete or carpeted concrete) are very dark. They are normally in the shadow of the seats. And, cellphone usage is usually prohibited. I worked in venues like these through high school and university.

Comment: @DeanF. It is interesting for you to bring this up. I never knew that smartphone are forbidden. I have never been to such a theatre myself. But given how well they dress themselves, it has to be a very classy theatre.

Comment: @J.Mini - The venue is well lit before, and after the performance and during intermission. The light sconces that you mentioned will be dimmed, but not extinguished during the performance. The light these would provide at that time would be insufficient for traversing an uneven area that may be inclined or include stairs. They are there for ambiance only. And, to make the lights from onstage seem not so glaring.

Comment: Think of a broadway play, an orchestra, a chorus, or an opera as an example. In the past, more events were held as formal dress events than there are now. And, cellphones going off are just as annoying in this type of scenario as it is in a movie theatre. It interrupts the enjoyment of the show for others. If you have to make/take a call, step outside. Flash photography disrupts the performers. And, recording of a show is forbidden as a matter of intellectual property and distribution rights. Although, the issue of recording is entirely up to the performance artists and production company.

Comment: @Yu Zhang  remember also that the film is set in 1981.  There were no such things as smartphones with torches back then.

Answer (score 2):

The [script](https://d2bu9v0mnky9ur.cloudfront.net/academy2019/screenplay/joker/joker_new_final.pdf) describes him as being *escorted by a bodyguard*, presumably because he said that he needed to go to the restroom.

> Arthur's really enjoying the movie, almost forgetting for a
> moment why he's there, when **he glances over to Thomas Wayne's
> box and sees him leaving, being led by his BODYGUARD—**
>
> Arthur's eyes go wide and he quickly turns to go, behind him
> on screen, the Tramp is rescued by the girl before he falls
> off the edge, orchestra swelling—

There are several mentions of how dark it is, so the bodyguard evidently has a torch to help Mr Wayne to pick out the stairs, avoid tripping, etc.